# Complicated PHP math conversion, on one line

Tags: php, math

Here's what I want to do:

A variable `$input` can equal any of the following values:`-2` `-1` `0` `1` `2`

I need to process this input so that the only possible results are `-1`, `0`, and `1`. Numbers should be converted to whatever of those is closest, so `-2` would turn into `-1`, `2` would turn into `1`, but `1`, `0`, and `-1` would all stay as they are.

I know how to do this using multiple lines, but I am sure there's some way to do this with some set of calculations nested together.

Does that make sense? Let me know if I should clarify.

Comment: You can put a whole program on a single line if you want. That doesn't make it a good idea...

Comment: It is a good idea in this case.

Comment: Never assume that what you are doing is a "good idea". There are always reasons for both sides (except in-line styles) that you may not have considered. In this case, readability could be one of them.

Comment: Alright, point taken. But I still would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know you are definitely going to get only those values, you can use:

```
<?php
$value = max(-1, min(1, $value));
?>
```

I would normally convert these to an integer explicity just in case.

```
<?php
$value = max(-1, min(1, intval($value)));
?>
```

Comment: This was almost exactly right. Using -2 and 2 makes it possible to get those values out. I switched it to `max(-1, min(1, $value));` and it works great.

Comment: Ahh good point. I've changed the answer to reflect your questions values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the GMP extension you can use:

```
int gmp_sign(resource $a);
```

Like this:

```
<?php $value = gmp_sign($value); ?>
```

If you don't have the GMP extension, then you can create such a function like so:

```
<?php
function sign( $number ) {
    return ( $number > 0 ) ? 1 : ( ( $number < 0 ) ? -1 : 0 );
}
```

Since the signs of -2 and -1 are negative, the above functions will return -1. The signs are 1 and 2 are positive, so the above functions will return 1. 0 has no sign, so the above functions will return 0.